# How to use ParseLogin-UI on Android with Parse-1.13.0.jar

Tags: android, parse-platform, parseui

It appears the `ParseUI-Android` project that is pulled from gradle isn't compatible with `Parse-1.13.0`. Specifically, the version pulled from gradle, the class `ParseSignupFragment.java` doesn't work with custom `ParseUser` objects. This has since been fixed and the `master` branch has the correct code in it.

Here's what I've done to try to solve this:

- Pulled the master branch
- Executed the gradle `assembleRelease` task
- Copied `ParseUI-Login/build/intermediates/bundles/release/classes.jar` into my Android `libs` directory
- Renamed `classes.jar` to `ParseUI-Login-0.0.1.jar`
- Added `compile files('libs/ParseUI-Login-0.0.1.jar')` to my `build.gradle`
- Executed a gradle build
- Fail

I obviously did something wrong, but I'm having a hard time trying to figure it out. Any thoughts or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you try to implement Parse.com, please, do not this. the project is closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not as far along migrating off parse to new ENV, so dont know if it will help. Below how i use ParseLogin-UI in projects ( i clone 1 subfolder of PLU to a project sub folder (ParseUI-Login) and just refer to it in build.gradle)

top level build.gradle...

```
> ext {
>     facebookSDK = 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.6.0'
>     androidSupport = 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.1'
>     bolts = 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.2.1'
>     parse = 'com.parse:parse-android:1.10.3'
>     parseFacebookUtils = 'com.parse:parsefacebookutils-v4-android:1.10.3@aar' }
```

app.build.gradle.dependencies ....

```
  compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.3.4'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.0.+'

    // rootProject.ext.* variables are defined in project gradle file, you can also use path here.
    compile rootProject.ext.facebookSDK
    compile project(':ParseUI-Login')
    compile rootProject.ext.androidSupport
    compile rootProject.ext.parse
    compile rootProject.ext.parseFacebookUtils
```

Comment: Thank you! That worked for me - I imported ParseLogin-UI and ParseLogin-Widget as modules into my app in Android Studio. Then I added them as dependencies as you suggested, and everything worked. I appreciate your response!